# Propensity score methods versus GLM for cost comparisons between treatment groups

Tags: propensity-scores

I'm working with a client that wants cost differences between two treatment groups. They have little background knowledge but have seen in the literature folks doing GLM gamma/log-link, etc. and are suggesting we do the same. However, for their purposes and the ease of the analysis, I want to suggest using IPTW to balance between the groups and compare cost directly using those weights. I need to strengthen my argument and I'd be happy to take suggestions on where to go.

Comment: This isn't an either or - there's no conflict between the methods. You can weight GLMs just as you can weight OLS.

Comment: I agree. The argument is using ONLY GLM or ONLY IPTW. I would be open to GLM after IPTW but I'm not willing to only use GLM without some form of propensity scoring method.

Comment: That's an unusual stance to take. The vast majority of GLMs are done without propensity weights.